# Plotting mean values using ggplot2 line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, line-plot

From the dataset shared, it can be observed that mean values for $C1 for factor 'Geminate in $Consonant are longer than 'Singleton'.

I want to plot $Place on the x-axis, and the mean values in $C1 on the y-axis for the factor column $Consonant.

```
Consonant     Place       C1 C1_xsampa
1  Singleton  Bilabial 149.8670        tS
2   Geminate  Bilabial 161.3066        tS
3  Singleton Retroflex 115.9713         f
4   Geminate Retroflex 143.3766         f
5  Singleton    Dental 130.1839         k
6  Singleton    Dental 118.7762         k
7   Geminate    Dental 122.1802         k
8  Singleton     Velar 112.3296         s
9   Geminate     Velar 142.4654         s
10 Singleton  Bilabial 245.7727        tS
11  Geminate  Bilabial 288.2960        tS
12  Geminate Retroflex 128.9104         f
13 Singleton    Dental 103.7978         k
14  Geminate    Dental 135.6264         k
15 Singleton    Dental 208.1685         k
```

I have attached a picture that exhibits a similar plot for your ease. I have spent days figuring this out. Any ideas would be immensely helpful.

[image: Similar plot]

############################EDIT#######################

```
Place C2_xsampa Consonant  C1
1      Velar         k Singleton 127
2      Velar        k:  Geminate 122
3   Bilabial         p Singleton 129
4   Bilabial        p:  Geminate 171
5     Dental       t_d Singleton 150
6     Dental      t_d:  Geminate 172
7     Dental     t_d_h Singleton 121
8     Dental    t_d_h:  Geminate 123
9  Retroflex        t` Singleton 109
10 Retroflex       t`:  Geminate 116
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your expected output is, but perhaps this solution will suit your use case:

```
library(tidyverse)
# summarySE func from
# http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/#Helper%20functions
## Gives count, mean, standard deviation, standard error of the mean, and confidence interval (default 95%).
##   data: a data frame.
##   measurevar: the name of a column that contains the variable to be summariezed
##   groupvars: a vector containing names of columns that contain grouping variables
##   na.rm: a boolean that indicates whether to ignore NA's
##   conf.interval: the percent range of the confidence interval (default is 95%)

summarySE <- function(data=NULL, measurevar, groupvars=NULL, na.rm=FALSE,
                      conf.interval=.95, .drop=TRUE) {
  library(plyr)
  # New version of length which can handle NA's: if na.rm==T, don't count them
  length2 <- function (x, na.rm=FALSE) {
    if (na.rm) sum(!is.na(x))
    else       length(x)
  }
  
  # This does the summary. For each group's data frame, return a vector with
  # N, mean, and sd
  datac <- ddply(data, groupvars, .drop=.drop,
                 .fun = function(xx, col) {
                   c(N    = length2(xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
                     mean = mean   (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm),
                     sd   = sd     (xx[[col]], na.rm=na.rm)
                   )
                 },
                 measurevar
  )
  
  # Rename the "mean" column    
  datac <- rename(datac, c("mean" = measurevar))
  
  datac$se <- datac$sd / sqrt(datac$N)  # Calculate standard error of the mean
  
  # Confidence interval multiplier for standard error
  # Calculate t-statistic for confidence interval: 
  # e.g., if conf.interval is .95, use .975 (above/below), and use df=N-1
  ciMult <- qt(conf.interval/2 + .5, datac$N-1)
  datac$ci <- datac$se * ciMult
  return(datac)
}

dat1 <- read.table(text = "rownumber Consonant     Place       C1 C1_xsampa
1  Singleton  Bilabial 149.8670        tS
2   Geminate  Bilabial 161.3066        tS
3  Singleton Retroflex 115.9713         f
4   Geminate Retroflex 143.3766         f
5  Singleton    Dental 130.1839         k
6  Singleton    Dental 118.7762         k
7   Geminate    Dental 122.1802         k
8  Singleton     Velar 112.3296         s
9   Geminate     Velar 142.4654         s
10 Singleton  Bilabial 245.7727        tS
11  Geminate  Bilabial 288.2960        tS
12  Geminate Retroflex 128.9104         f
13 Singleton    Dental 103.7978         k
14  Geminate    Dental 135.6264         k
15 Singleton    Dental 208.1685         k",
                   header = TRUE)

tgc <- summarySE(dat1, measurevar = "C1", groupvars = c("Consonant", "Place"))

ggplot(tgc, aes(x=Place, y=C1,
                colour=Consonant,
                group = Consonant)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=C1-se,
                    ymax=C1+se),
                width = 0.2,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_line(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))
```

[image: example_1.png]

Answer (score 0):

One should count the means before feeding the data to ggplot. group_by() and summarise() from dplyr package along with pipe operator %>% from magrittr package will manage this smoothly.

If the data above is stored in object "data", then

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(magrittr)
    library(ggplot2)

    avg_data <- data %>% group_by(Consonant, Place) %>%
        summarise(mean_C1 = mean(C1))

    ggplot(avg_data, aes(Place, mean_C1, color = Consonant)) +
        geom_point()
```

Should give what you are looking for: [Means of C1 per consonant and place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM7sV.png).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am able to follow what you said. However, as mentioned in the question, this does not provide me with the desired output.  I have edited the question by posting the mean values. Please have a look with respect to the sample plot picture posted.

Comment: You should clearly point out in the original question which aspects are expected to appear in the output. Are exact shapes or colors meaningful, and which values should the lines under and above a point (or shape) represent?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. 
As one can see, the difference in numerical C2 is not very different between factors, Singleton and Geminate. Consider this way: Instead of two factors (Voiced - Voiceless) from the image provided, I wish the output to depict all four factors listed in $Place for Singleton and Geminate on the x-axis, and their C2 value on the y-axis. I want the output this way so as to show non-significant difference between Singleton and Geminate at all four factors in $Place. 
I hope this suffices.

Comment: ADD: Multiple plots are also fine with me.